# Entering spaces in a validated input field (useForm)

Tags: reactjs, use-form

there is a question that has puzzled me for some time now.
The firstName input field should allow the user to enter spaces (before \ after \ in the middle of the word).
I added `inputRef` property to validate this field. Adding this property immediately disallowed any spaces in the field. Is there any way to remove this ban on entering spaces?

```
const form = useForm<NameFormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: '',
      middleName: '',
      lastName: '',
      suffix: ''
    }
  });

const formValues = form.watch();
const { setValue } = form;

const firstNameInput = React.useMemo(
() => (
  <TextField
    error={Boolean(form.errors.firstName)}
    autoFocus={process.env.PLATFORM !== 'ios'}
    inputProps={{ style: { textOverflow: 'ellipsis' }, maxLength: 26 }}
    margin="normal"
    variant="outlined"
    name="firstName"
    inputRef={form.register({
      required: t('kyc.legal-name.validation.not-empty'),
      validate: {
        length: (value) => value.length <= 26 || t('kyc.legal-name.validation.incorrect-first-name')
      }
    })}
    onChange={(event) => setValue('firstName', event.target.value.trim())}
    helperText={form.errors.firstName ? form.errors.firstName.message : ''}
  />
),
[form, setValue, t]
```

);

Answer (score 0):

your onChange prop that sets firstName is trimming user input so the user will not be able to enter any white space characters. if you want to keep the white space it should be like this:

```
onChange={(event) => setValue('firstName', event.target.value)}
```

Comment: What if I need to trim the spaces at the beginning and at the end, but allow the user to put one space between words?

Comment: it would be best if you do not usually do that while the user is typing. you can do this before submitting the form as part of your validation.
if you really want to do that in real-time, my suggestion is to do it via `onblur` event or wait a few seconds after the user finished typing and then apply trim.